# Conflicting URL rewrite rules

Tags: wordpress, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I have two URL rewrite rules. Individually they work perfectly, but when both are turned on, they are conflicting.

The first is in my root dir web.config, takes all requests to files in /seo/ and serves them by requests in the root of the website.

```
<rule name="RewriteToFile">
    <match url="^(?!seo/)(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="seo/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

The next one is in the web.config in a sub directory called /blog (it's a Wordpress blog).

```
<rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
    <match url="*"/>
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
        </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
</rule>
```

Individually turned on, they work fine, but if both of them are on, the blog will only serve 403's...

Is there a way to enable both of these rules?